# Как в один столбец таблицы вставить несколько значений из другой. SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, foreign-key

Есть 2 таблицы, которые связаны между собой внешним ключом.

[image: Таблица авторы][image: таблица книги]

Каким образом в столбец таблицы `books` можно добавить несколько значений `id` из `authors`? Обычная ситуация из жизни. У книги имеются несколько авторов.

Comment: Может быть, считать коллектив авторов самостоятельным (обобщенным) автором? В противном случае придется заводить отдельные поля: author1, author2 и т.д.

Comment: @anshap. Я передумал это делать. Идея норм, но авторов может быть и 5, и 10. Так что лучше создать таблицу со связями или отдельную таблицу с авторами, позволять выбрать авторов только из нее.